# Rails update several records based on their fields value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, arel

I have a `Subscription` model with a `price` field and my last migration introduced a field called `per_month_price`. I am looking for a method which can update records faster than a simple `.each {...}`. For example:

`Subscription.update_all {|c| c.per_month_price = c.price/12}`

Comment: My bad, I have retracted my close vote. @MarekLipka thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You could wrap it in a transaction to save some cycles on pre- and post processing (create index etc.) I do however think that performance should not be too critical here, because it is run-once code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not simply use

```
Subscription.update_all( "per_month_price = price / 12" )
```

This is working. It takes the statement and runs for all found records.
This is very common in rails.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Please check before downvote!

Comment: Like described in http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all. There is no need to get a parameter from outside. So it runs the sql statement fills the price / 12 into per_month_price.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it in raw sql. I'm not sure that the syntax is standard SQL, it may not work with all DBs

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('UPDATE Subscription SET per_month_price = price / 12')
```

It seems ok with [mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why add it to the database at all if it can be determined programatically from an existing column? Just create a virtual attribute:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  .
  .
  .

  def per_month_price
    self.price / 12
  end

  def per_month_price=(arg)
    self.price = arg*12
  end

end
```

This will function the same as if you had a `per_month_price` column in your DB. It'll be more efficient as you won't have to hit the database so much, and it eliminates the (very likely) possibility that the `price` and `per_month_price` columns will become inconsistent with eachother somewhere, e.g. if you update one but forget to update the other.

Sorry that I didn't directly answer your question (especially to anyone coming here through Google), but this seems like a much better design to me.